# Real method solving $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 K_0(x)^5I_0(x)\left ( \pi^2I_0(x)^2-K_0(x)^2 \right ) \text{d}x=\frac{\pi^4}{128}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-integration, bessel-functions

Define two zero order Bessel functions:
$$
K_0(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x\cosh(t)}\text{d}t\quad \text{for}\operatorname{Re}(x)>0
$$
$$
I_0(x)=\frac1\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x\cos(t)}\text{d}t
$$
By considering the function $$f(z)=z^3{K_0(z)}^4{K_0(-z)}^4$$, it is known that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} 
x^3 K_0(x)^5I_0(x)\left ( \pi^2I_0(x)^2-K_0(x)^2 \right ) 
\text{d}x=\frac{\pi^4}{128}.$$

---

*My question would be*: Can we do that one in real methods? **Just for curiosity**. I have tried several integral transformations but failed. Multiple integration also suggests no result. But there's still a possibility that I don't get on the right way. So I need your cures.

Comment: man this looks nasty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it.
[Take a look at here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.01068)